# SQL Server - Do automatically created column statistics get dropped automatically after time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, optimization, statistics

The retired SQL Server 2000 documentation https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51958 states:

> "The statistics generated for a column can be deleted if you no longer
>   want to retain and maintain them. Statistics created on columns by SQL
>   Server (when the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS database option is set to ON)
>   are aged and dropped automatically."

Obviously this is old documentation related to SQL Server 2000, but I can't find anything official that is more current and says otherwise or that the behaviour is different now.  Can anyone answer definitively?  Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server, under no version or circumstance, will automatically remove statistics objects, unless the underlying object (table/view/index) is removed.

Use `DROP STATISTICS ...` T-SQL or use the SSMS GUI to drop unnecessary statistics, but only do that if you are certain they are not needed.